# Does the core data migration depend on the amount of table rows have been edited?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 2 core data models with the same amount of table/rows. I've just renamed few rows (without adding new ones)

Is the core data migration slowness proportional to the amount of table rows that have been edited ? Or does it just depend on how big is the database ?

In other words, if I migrate between 2 models that are exactly the same (all fields have been mepped to themselves), is the migration supposed to be extremely fast, or depends on how big are the models ?

thanks

I've uploaded the conversion log: http://cl.ly/3H1v252R1p1c

ps. Not sure why I have several lines with CREATE/INSERT statements, even if I'm not altering any table in my database. I've just added a new table to my database and I haven't mapped it to any table in the previous database.

This is the code (I've tried to change all parameters, and remove the pragmaOptions, but it is always slow.

```
 NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"DBname.sqlite"]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary *pragmaOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [pragmaOptions setObject:@"OFF" forKey:@"synchronous"];
    [pragmaOptions setObject:@"0" forKey:@"fullfsync"];

    NSDictionary *storeOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                                       NSSQLiteStoreType, NSStoreTypeKey,
                                       pragmaOptions, NSSQLitePragmasOption,
                                      nil]; 

    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    [persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:storeOptions error:&error];
```

**UDPATE**: Example of suspicious re-insert

```
2013-06-13 09:38:44.114 MyApp[7415:907] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZITEM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZSECTION, ZUNIQUEID, ZBIN, ZDISPLAYNAME, ZSORTNAME) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2013-06-13 09:38:44.116 MyApp[7415:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)8
2013-06-13 09:38:44.117 MyApp[7415:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = (int64)8
2013-06-13 09:38:44.118 MyApp[7415:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = (int64)1
2013-06-13 09:38:44.120 MyApp[7415:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[3] = nil
2013-06-13 09:38:44.121 MyApp[7415:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[4] = 119
2013-06-13 09:38:44.123 MyApp[7415:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[5] = 0
2013-06-13 09:38:44.124 MyApp[7415:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[6] = "PG-13 (Parents Strongly Cautioned)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the launch argument `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3` then you can actually
see the migration process. For example, renaming `timeStamp` to `timeStamp2` in a `Event`
entity
 produced
the following output:

```
ALTER TABLE ZEVENT RENAME TO _T_ZEVENT
CREATE TABLE ZEVENT ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZTIMESTAMP2 TIMESTAMP ) 
INSERT INTO ZEVENT (Z_PK,Z_ENT,Z_OPT,ZTIMESTAMP2) SELECT Z_PK,Z_ENT,Z_OPT,nil FROM _T_ZEVENT
DROP TABLE _T_ZEVENT
```

You can see that the old table is renamed, a new table created and filled and then the
old table discarded. This confirms your conjecture that the time for the migration is proportional to the total size of all tables that have been modified.

Comment: I haven't changed anything in my database but I actually have several INSERT statement. Not sure why.

Comment: @Patrick: Do you perform a lightweight migration or an explicit migration? Perhaps you can show the code related to the creation of the models and the persistent store.

Comment: @Patrick: Perhaps it is related to your `pragmaOptions`. What happens if you omit these?

Comment: I've tried, it is the same, I've tried to change all other settings, but it doesn't work. In any case, the pragmaOptions are set to get best performance out of it.

Comment: But can you confirm me, given the log, that all data are reinserted even if the tables don't change? I believe this is why it is slow.

Comment: @Patrick: Is the log *only* from the `addPersistentStoreWithType` call? - Perhaps single-step in the debugger to get only the log output of the migration.

Comment: Yes that's the log only from the addPersistentStoreWithType call, well beside the first 2 lines.. Not sure if it is the log is about the migration only, or migration+creation of the new database, since all is done inside such call. But I believe I should not see INSERT statements if all tables are the same (as in my case, there is only a new table which is not mapped to the previous model).

Comment: @Patrick: It seems to me that SQLite is performing a "VACUUM" options (which rebuilds the database to reduce the fragmentation). I have no idea how to control this from Core Data, but there is a "pragma auto_vacuum=2" line in the debug output which I do not have in my test app. Did you set any options that might be related to this?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I've set [pragmaOptions setObject:@"0" forKey:@"auto_vacuum"]; and in the log I've now CoreData: sql: pragma auto_vacuum=0. But the speed is the same, it seems that wasn't the reason. In your log do you also have the same lines such as CREATE TABLE and INSERT data ? Is that a normal migration log, or is it reinserting all data again ?

Comment: @Patrick: In my test case I had only CREATE/INSERT statements (if I remember correctly) only for the Z_PRIMARYKEY table. But I did not experience that *all* tables were rewritten. But I do not have my logfile anymore, so I would have to reproduce that later (when I have more time). - Actually I would recommend that you file a bug at Apple.

Comment: CREATE statement is used only for PRIMARYKEY for me too. However there are more INSERT statements, I believe they are not related with the PRIMARYKEY. I've pasted an example in the question ("PG-13 (Parents Strongly Cautioned)" is real data in the database).